# Inserting multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have a string with tag names separated by comas ready for insertion into a MySQL table, for example:

```
$tags = " 'pigs','dogs','cats' "
```

I have a mySQL table called **tags** containing a **tag_id** and **tag_name**.

I want to insert each tag into the table. Is this possible in one INSERT query using the string I have, or will I have to run a loop with an array of the tag names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag_name`) VALUES(". implode('),(', explode(',', trim($tags))) . ")";
```

And if you were to echo out `$sql` you should get:

```
INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag_name`) VALUES('pigs'),('dogs'),('cats')
```

Answer (score 0):

it's code

```
<?php
$tags = " 'pigs','dogs','cats' ";
$ary_tags = explode(",", trim($tags));
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag_name`) VALUES";
foreach($ary_tags as $t) {
        $sql .= "({$t}),";
}
$sql =  rtrim($sql, ',');
$sql .= ';';
echo $sql;
?>
```